# Set tab's title from fragment on the fly

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, fragment, onchange

I have on activity (MainActivity) and it has five tabs, each tab contains a fragment. Each fragment contains an `EditText` widget. I'd like to set the active tab's title when I change the text of the EditText in the active fragment's class. How could I do that on the fly ? 
Here are my resources:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

SectionPagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
                return tab4;
            case 4:
                Tab5 tab5 = new Tab5();
                return tab5;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "title1";
            case 1:
                return "title2";
            case 2:
                return "title3";
            case 3:
                return "title4";
            case 4:
                return "title5";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

These are generated by Android Studio, so I guess I should go from here. What I want, if I have an `EditText` on the Tab1, and I start to type in it, it changes the first tab's title from "title1" to the string I typed.

Comment: do you have a button where you want to press after typing in edittext and changes title??? Or you want to change title as you type in edittext?

Comment: I'd prefer the solution where I can change the title by typing. But I could use a button if it is the only way (or significantly easier way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From edittext you should use `addTextChangedListener` on `EditText` within that `TextWatcher` instance to change title on the fly. Refer this code.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //this is your tab index you want to change title of..
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Actually it works. I have to add that, I made the MainActivity's tabLayout a public static variable, then I was able to modify it with your code in this way: 
`MainActivity.tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(s);`